# Making a variable accessible to other methods

Tags: c#, silverlight, variables, arraylist

I have an arraylist called 'pri1', I want this array list to be available to other methods:

```
void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Stream responseStream = e.Result;
                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

                string[] split1 = Regex.Split(response, "},{");
                List<string> pri1 = new List<string>(split1);
                pri1.RemoveAt(0);
                string last = pri1[pri1.Count() - 1];
                pri1.Remove(last);

                List<string> str = pri1;
            }
        }
```

so a suggestion to me was to save it to a class variable which i did:

```
private List<string> str = new List<string>();
```

unfortunately the elements of 'pri1' did not successfully pass on to 'str':

```
 void AddPrimaryMarkerGraphics(object sender, getPrimaryListCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
         foreach (string item in str)
          {
```

So I was wondering where in these 3 steps did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My *guess* is that you've still declared a new local variable within your `downloader_OpenReadCompleted` instead of assigning to the existing variable:

```
pri1.RemoveAt(0);
string last = pri1[pri1.Count() - 1];
pri1.Remove(last);
str = pri1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you accidently declared a new variable `str` instead of assigning to the existing field.

replace this last line of code:

```
   List<string> str = pri1;
```

with this:

```
   this.str = pri1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

```
List<string> str = pri1;
```

remove above line

and

modify your last foreach to the following

```
 foreach (string item in pri)
```

Comment: pri is a local variable in a different function... i don't think thats going to work.